# Why am I getting an Illegal Token error in my case statement boolean assignment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use the same syntax in other switch case statements which work. I basically create an empty object and start adding in key value pairs to it:

```
var vs = $scope;
vs.toggleTimeSpan = function(string) {

    vs.time.span = {};

    switch(string) {
        case '1h':
            // vs.time.span[1h] = true;
            vs.time.span.1h = true;
            break;

        case '1d':
            vs.time.span.1d = true;
            break;

        case '1m':
            vs.time.span.1mo = true;
            break;

        case '1y':
            vs.time.span.1yr = true;
            break;

        case 'max':
            vs.time.span.max = true;
            break;
    }
};
```

[image]

Here is where I intend on using the `vs.time.span` object:

```
<ul class="timescale">
    <li ng-class="{'active':time.span.1h}"
        ng-click="toggleTimeSpan('1h')">1 h</li>

    <li ng-class="{'active':time.span.1d}"
        ng-click="toggleTimeSpan('1d')">1 d</li>

    <li ng-class="{'active':time.span.1mo}"
        ng-click="toggleTimeSpan('1mo')">1 mo</li>

    <li ng-class="{'active':time.span.1yr}"
        ng-click="toggleTimeSpan('1yr')">1 yr</li>

    <li ng-class="{'active':time.span.max}"
        ng-click="toggleTimeSpan('max')">max</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note, I just figured out I needed to use `Array` syntax `vs.timeSpan.push({ span: '1h' });` still will mark the correct answer to explain the wrong logic used above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  cannot use a key name starting with numbers. Variable  should either start with letters or $ or _. Try to rename your keys with name like one_hour instead of 1h its should work.

Comment: Ah thanks! :) shorter code and don't have to do something like: `'active':timeSpan[0].span == '1h'`